# System.TypeLoadException occurred in Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity

Tags: windows, uwp

I am trying to attach an event handler in ListView with Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity in my UWP application. When I select a row in ListView, the application executes a procedure according to the selected item.

So, I've installed the "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed" package and changed a XAML file like this:

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          x:Name="listBoxobj"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="10,0,0,10"
          Background="White"
          Foreground="Black"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Tools}"
          SelectedItem= "{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=Twoway}"
          SelectionMode="Single">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick" SourceObject="listBoxObj">
                    <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Tool_Clicked}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And the following has been implemented in its ViewModel:

```
private System.Windows.Input.ICommand tool_Clicked;
public ICommand Tool_Clicked
{
    get {
        return tool_Clicked;
    }
    set {
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(tool_Clicked, value))
        {
            tool_Clicked = value as RelayCommand;
            OnPropertyChanged("Tool_Clicked");
        }
    }
}
public DisplayViewModel()
{
...
    Tool_Clicked = new RelayCommand(SelectionChanged);
...
}
public void SelectionChanged(object arg) {
 ... executes some procedures according to the selected item...
}
```

But when I tested these codes, the following exception has emitted:
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not find Windows Runtime type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand'.'

In Debug mode, on the other hand, no such exception has been thrown.
So, I have two questions:

1. I wonder what is the difference betweeen the Debug mode and the Release mode.
2. Are there any way to avoid throwing the System.TypeLoadException?

***Update 1:***
I have configured the compile options at Release mode.

- I've checked "Compile with .NET native tool chain"
- I've checked "unsafe code".

But when I tried to build my project, it has ended with the following error message:
error :  MCG0018:TypeExpected Type File or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.PropertyType' not found.

When I tried unchecking "Compile with .NET native tool chain", I could run this code. I think some of the nuget packages I use don't support .NET native code...

***Update 2:***

I've made the RelayCommand class like the following:

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<Object> _execute;
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) :
            this(execute, null)
        { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/dotnet-native/

Comment: What is the RelayCommand class? Are you using MVVM light package in your project?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I've made the custom RelayCommand class which extends ICommand class. The source codes have been added in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your question has been solved on Microsoft Q&A-[System.TypeLoadException occurs in the Release Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/513901/systemtypeloadexception-occurs-in-the-release-mode.html) by Nico.

To make Nico's answer short, you could use the `Tapped` event instead of using the `click` event. Then you could use the current datacontext as parameter

Code like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                 <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                     <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                         <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=listBoxObj, Path=DataContext.Tool_Clicked}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                     </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                 </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
             </TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for having shared the code above.
I 've changed my code and an event successfully emitted. 
But in this code, due to the CommandParameter is Binding, the event handler for it receives a ViewModel class, not an item in the ListView. That's why I also manage SelectedIndex property in the ListView. I wonder it is all right.

Comment: @YoshiteruKageyama That's all right. You can't directly pass the item using the command.

Comment: OK. I understand this mechanism. Thank you so much for having some comments.